# Magento 1.9 - Multi Store Product URL Issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I had Magento 1.9 website which runs with default store only.

Now I have created 1 more store for USA customers with currency $.

Now issue is why every product have 2 urls, different URL for both stores. There is an issue and duplicate content issue with SEO, So I want only 1 URL for both stores.

Ex:
**Product:** XYZ
**Store India URL:** xyz.html with price in INR
**Store USA URL:** xyz.html with price in $

I have used one extension which redirect me on specific store based on user IP.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only currency changed than used Magento currency converter in top template file.

Disable store and used only single store.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check URL Rewrite Management  in Magento 
You can see the url re-write details there
_admin->catalog->URL Rewrite Management 
you can add manually url re-write settings there

also you can check another method 
1)back up the table "core_url_rewrite"
2)truncate the tabel "core_url_rewrite".
3)re-index 
and check the URL Rewrite Management part
**please do not  forget to  take back of the table**

Answer (score 0):

you could go for two stores using hreflang. this would solve dc issue.
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en